# ngnix app directory configuration

Tags: php, heroku, yii, nginx

i male nginx custom configuration in nginx with Procfile
so i make new file with name Procfile with this code

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx_app.conf
```

and new file with nginx_app.conf with this code

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass heroku-fcgi;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

so in my heroku app dir have two folder as yii (yii framework supporting file  ) and second is document root folder where is my app so i want two now where we have to declare document root dir in nginx_app.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching i solved this issue

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx // put your custom nginx file //space with folder name
```

and for removing index.php

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last; //add here index.php
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass heroku-fcgi;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

So it will configure with any framework

Comment: You probably mean `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C custom_nginx.conf myapp/`, so "myapp/" is the document root, right? This "answer" you gave yourself really does not make this clear at all.

Comment: if you know then you can reply the first other wise i search and try its work ok. so is not fake thing .

Comment: I did not say it was fake. I'm saying that your `// add blah here` comments and your explanation are confusing. Someone who finds this question will not understand the answer. Your question was how to specify the document root (and change it to for example `myapp/`), correct?